# Laravel Migrations self-referencing foreign key General error: 1005 Can't create table

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, migration, laravel

Why do I have a problem creating a table using Laravel Migrations Schema Builder?

The problem occurs with a table with a self-referencing foreign key.

```
Schema::create('cb_category', function($table)
{
    $table->integer('id')->primary()->unique()->unsigned();
    $table->integer('domain_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')->on('cb_domain'); 
    $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable(); 
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('cb_category')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('level');
});
```

> `` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'eklik2.#sql-7d4_e' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `cb_category` add constraint cb_category_parent_id_foreign foreign key (`parent_id`) references `cb_category` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade) (Bindings: array ()) ``
>
> `[PDOException]`
>
> `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'eklik2.#sql-7d4_e' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to break this into two Schema blocks, one creating the columns, the other adding the FKs. mysql can't do both at the same time.

Comment: I have break it in 2 statements, anyway the error remains:   
   
Schema::create(...);    
    
Schema::table('cb_category', function($table){
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('cb_category')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 
});

Comment: Solved with breaking. Here is the code:    
Schema::create('cb_category', function($table){... });    
$dbh = DB::getPdo();    
$dbh->query("ALTER TABLE cb_category ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cb_category_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES cb_category (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION");

Answer (score 11):

Two querys work :

```
Schema::create('cb_category', function($table)
{
    $table->integer('id')->primary()->unique()->unsigned();
    $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();  
});

Schema::table('cb_category', function (Blueprint $table) 
{
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('cb_category')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: This sure seems like the right answer. Worked fine and makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

I may be too late for the party, but the official docs claim that the foreign key, in case of integer, must be `->unsigned();`

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys

> Note: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing
>   integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned.

Also, Artisan does not fail if you (as I have) misspell `unsigned()` and I have spent quite a few hours trying to figure out why the key was not created.

So two things:
1. Always make the foreign key column unsigned in case of incrementing integers
2. Check the spelling of `unsigned()`

Answer (score 3):

Also a late response but probably a more **idiomatic** way for **Laravel 8**:

```php
use App\Models\CbCategory;

...

Schema::create("cb_category", function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(CbCategory::class, "parent_id")
        ->constrained()
        ->cascadeOnUpdate()
        ->cascadeOnDelete()
        ->nullable();
});
```

> **Please Note:** I guessed the class name of `CbCategory` here. Using the class reference firsthand (instead of the former table name string) enables your static code checkers to pick up on future class name changes.
> Also the `_id`-suffix at the `parent_id` column name is important.

---

May the following resources quench your thirst for knowledge:

- `id()`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-id
- `foreignIdFor()`: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html
- `cascadeOnDelete()` & `cascadeOnUpdate()`: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/ForeignKeyDefinition.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->on('categories')->references('id');
    });
```

i got same error when i used this code, after change "$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()" to "$table->bigInteger('parent_id');"
my problem solved.

The point here is to make sure that the type of foreign key is the same as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('cb_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('domain_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')->on('cb_domain');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('cb_category')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('level');
    });
```

Try this

Comment: This has the same problem as in the question. A table cannot be made to reference itself as it is created, because the table does not exist to reference while it is being created,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have **another table that references** the current table that you want to create.
I had this problem and remove that table and my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 8+ you don't have to break into two Schema blocks. You can use
`foreignIdFor(CbCategory::class, 'cb_category_id')` and it will create a column named `cb_category_id`

Ex.

```
Schema::create("cb_category", function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(CbCategory::class, 'cb_category_id')->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
});
```

**Any additional column modifiers (Ex. nulleable) must be called before the constrained method.**

You can use a second parameter in foreignIdFor for the referencing column name (in case it isn't 'id') **NOT for the name you want it to have**, in your case the name will automatically be 'cb_category_id'

Answer (score 0):

BIG

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table){
$table->id();
$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('restrict');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).